# Initial public offerings

Tags: data-request, usa, finance, companies

All pre-IPO companies fill the SEC form S-1. It mentions underwriters, offering price, executives, and financials. [Example for Etsy.](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1370637/000119312515077045/d806992ds1.htm)

This information is available via SEC and elsewhere, but not structured.

Have you seen a structured dataset of these forms or other IPO-related information online?

Comment: A lot of places have trends on the # of IPOs but not information on each IPO which is what it seems you a seeking. Check out http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/ICPSR/studies/34944 though the data does not appear to be available to the public :(

Answer (score 2):

Try [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/collections/usa/usa-startups-venture-capital). It has info on startups and venture capital, you might find IPO info in there or a link to what you want.

> This is Quandl's data collection on US startups, entrepreneurship, angel investments and venture capital.
>
> Quandl's startup data includes number of investments, investment size, and valuation data at each stage of the startup financing pipeline: seed and angel investments, early-stage venture capital including Series A, late-stage venture capital and growth equity, and exits including IPOs and acquisitions. The data is organized by time across different sectors, stages and states.
>
> Source for Quandl's data on entrepreneurship, angel investing and venture capital in the USA include the Bureau of Labor Statistics, the National Venture Capital Association, the Center for Venture Research, the Cooley Venture Financing Report, the Kauffman Foundation, and Crunchbase.
>
> Click on any indicator name or graph to see a full, freely-downloadable historical time series of that data. All datasets on Quandl are also available via our free and unrestricted [API](https://www.quandl.com/help/api).